# TypeError: Constraints must be defined using a dictionary

Tags: python, optimization, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am trying to run minimize function using LinearConstraint function on a correlation matrix but LinearConstraint expects a dictionary of constraints and i do not fully understand how i should  assign linear constraints in a dictionary using "LinearConstraint' function. Any suggestion is appreciated.

followed below page but still i could not figure out the solution: \

> stackoverflow.com/a/52003654

Below is data used:

```
col1      col2     col3
   1        0.59  0.68
   0.59  1        0.92
   0.68 0.92  1
```

Below function is used to calculate.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize, LinearConstraint

A0 = [.3,.4,.3]
bnds = [(1, 1) for i in range(len(A0))]

def test(w):   
    return (w@np.matrix(corr))@w

temp=minimize(test,A0,constraints=(LinearConstraint(np.array([1,1,1]),lb=1.0,ub=1.0), ))
```

Below is error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\slsqp.py in _minimize_slsqp(func, x0, args, jac, bounds, constraints, maxiter, ftol, iprint, disp, eps, callback, **unknown_options)
    253         try:
--> 254             ctype = con['type'].lower()
    255         except KeyError:

TypeError: 'LinearConstraint' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-332-ce6c477d5282> in <module>
      8     return (w@np.matrix(corr))@w
      9 
---> 10 temp=minimize(test,A0,constraints=(LinearConstraint(np.array([1,1,1]),lb=1.0,ub=1.0), ))

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py in minimize(fun, x0, args, method, jac, hess, hessp, bounds, constraints, tol, callback, options)
    609     elif meth == 'slsqp':
    610         return _minimize_slsqp(fun, x0, args, jac, bounds,
--> 611                                constraints, callback=callback, **options)
    612     elif meth == 'trust-constr':
    613         return _minimize_trustregion_constr(fun, x0, args, jac, hess, hessp,

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\slsqp.py in _minimize_slsqp(func, x0, args, jac, bounds, constraints, maxiter, ftol, iprint, disp, eps, callback, **unknown_options)
    256             raise KeyError('Constraint %d has no type defined.' % ic)
    257         except TypeError:
--> 258             raise TypeError('Constraints must be defined using a '
    259                             'dictionary.')
    260         except AttributeError:

TypeError: Constraints must be defined using a dictionary.
```